# Too large font in the question names

Tags: discussion

Previously much more questions could fit one page in the question list. Currently the font is giant and the information is much less dense.

Comment: Have you clicked 'show 50 questions' button? The number of questions is not determined by font size.

Comment: This is potentially the sort of thing we can tweak in a (to come later, probably) redesign of the site styling.